# what kind of database is best for storing audio files?

Tags: mysql, database, web, nosql

I'm building a website which allows the user to download audio files from various movies. where do I need to store this audio files? Is it enough to store files as blob format in MySQL or should I need to use any NoSQL database? If we store only metadata file in MySQL then where should I store the actual file?

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, as I've not really had much experience mixing files and databases; but I think the standard practice is to let the application/appserver/website store it, and the database to record where it was stored (and perhaps it's original file name if necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Sahil said, you don't really store the files in the database, but rather, you store links to the files in the database.  Every system I know of that stores large numbers of big files stores them externally to the database.  You store all of the queryable data for the file (title, artist, length, etc.) in the database, along with a partial path to the file. When it's time to retrieve the file, you extract the file's path, prepend some file root (or URL) to it, and return that.  Finally, you probably want datatype varchar for the field names that point to the actual files.

Comment: can you suggest some links where I could learn from examples?

Comment: Oh I see so something like store the audio files in AWS S3 and then read the file paths

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually store files directly in a database, you have store it in a separate file or folder. MySQL does allow you to do it directly but there's a limit.